# Can components be interacted with when their visibility is set to GONE?

Tags: android, android-view

I could not find anything that straight out answers this question. If I set the component (such as a Button, ListView, EditText) in the xml with a visibility of GONE, am I still able to interact with those components even though they are invisible? I tested it out with a Button and it seems to be no but I want to make sure.

Comment: When you set visibility GONE component or view is there in view but no longer visible and it will release their space to other views but when you set visibility to INVISIBLE it will not shown but space will be not release to other views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the visibility is set to GONE, the component is removed from the view hierarchy and no space is set aside for it. Moreover, there is no way for the user to interact with it (However, changes made to the `View` by the programmer while it is `GONE` become manifest when the visibility is changed to `VISIBLE`).

When the visibility is set to INVISIBLE, the component is still actually present in the view hierarchy, and space is calculated for it.

Comment: When a view's visibility is set to gone, it won't be visually created but other than that you can access it programmatically the same as any other view, including all of it's properties. So I wouldn't say that you can not interact with the view.

Comment: The view is not present in the view hierarchy, so any changes you apply to the view are redundant.

Comment: No they are not, once you change the view visibility to lets say `visible` all your changes will take effect. So for example if you changed the `text` of a `TextView` when the view was `GONE`, it will have the changed text when you make it visible again.

Comment: While the `View` is `GONE`, any changes will most certainly be redundant. If anyone wanted to make changes to the `View`, they'd first make it `VISIBLE`. I was pointing out the difference between `GONE` and `INVISIBLE`.